# How do you change the color of a text layer in After Effects 2017 using ExtendScript?

Tags: extendscript, after-effects

I need to know how to change the color of a text layer in After Effects 2017 using ExtendScript. I can change the text itself very simply, like so:

```
var comp=app.project.item(10);
comp.layer(1).property('Source Text').setValue('My Text Here');
```

But how do I set the color of that text layer? I would think this would be very simple but despite much searching I haven't found anything that clearly explains how to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Page 182 of the [After Effects CS6 Scripting guide](https://blogs.adobe.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/48/files/2012/06/After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf?file=2012/06/After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf) (the most recent documentation that Adobe have deigned to give us) describes the TextDocument object, which is the data type for a text layer's Source Text property. Amongst the attributes is fillColor and strokeColor.

**edit** it's not as simple as it seems, you can't just assign the values to the source text, you have to make a new textDocument object, make your changes to it, and then assign the value of the source text property to the textDocument object you created.

So you can set it thus:

```js
var textProp = comp.layer(1).property('Source Text');
//make a new textDocument, copying the values of the current one
var textDocument = textProp.value;
// change any attributes of the textDocument here, e.g.:
textDocument.fillColor = [R, G, B];
// write the textDocument over the existing one
textProp.setValue(textDocument);
```

R, G and B are floating-point values, where 1.0 ⇒ 255 in 8-bit colour.

You can also see that scripting guide online at [aeenhancers](http://docs.aenhancers.com/textdocument/#textdocument-fillcolor) There's a typo where it describes the constructor, it says `newTextDocument` it should be `new TextDocument`

Comment: I tried that. It doesn't change the color of the layer. For instance, I used this...

var comp=app.project.item(17);
comp.layer(1).property('Source Text').fillColor = c;

Where c is [255,255,255]... but the text does not change to white.

Comment: try `[1,1,1]` the value is a floating point number between 0 and 1 for 8-bit projects, where 1 maps to 255

Comment: dangit, forgot to add `.value` to get the value of source text. I've amended my answer.

Comment: That didn't work either. I actually read the docs and worked it out. You can't just assign a value to a text document, you have to make the changes to a duplicate TextDocument object and then assign it as the source text.

Comment: That did it thanks! I voted for your answer but I don't have enough reputation for it to show up yet.